# Неожиданная ошибка при обращении к контракту Ethereum через web3.js

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Неожиданная ошибка при обращении к контракту Ethereum через web3.js

```
MyContract.methods.actual_balance("0xE8D.........").call({})
.then(r=>{
    console.log(r)
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

Возвращает ошибку про газ.

```
{ Error: Returned error: err: max fee per gas less than block base fee: address 0x4..., maxFeePerGas: 3000000000 baseFee: 42784084648 (supplied gas 4700000)...
```

На такого не может быть, ведь я не отправляю транзакцию а просто считываю состояние чейна. Как такое возможно?
Раньше все работало и вдруг сломалось.

Comment: переведите пожалуйста ваш вопрос на русский язык, в противном случае он будет закрыт из-за несоответствия требованиям

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую. Но я хотел задать вопрос англоязычному сообществу.

Comment: англоязычное сообщество находится здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/ :D вы можете и там задать вопрос тоже, если там получите ответ, то после того как переведете его можете здесь опубликовать тоже

Comment: Спасибо, уже начал задавать, но надо 90 минут подождать.

Answer (score 0):

Как не странно но проблема была в gasPrice в настройках контракта. Не думал что низкая цена может вызвать ошибку у метода .call(), который просто считывает локально информацию из чейна.